# What is the authenticity of the du'a "O Allah, bless us in Rajab and Sha‘baan, and let us reach Ramadan"?

Tags: dua, authenticity, reference-request

Many Muslim scholars or at least Imams of Jumu'ah prayer use to say this du'a (supplication):

> O Allah, bless us in Rajab and Sha‘baan, and let us reach Ramadan
>
> اللهم بارك لنا في رجب وشعبان وبلغنا رمضان

in Rajab and Sha'baan (the two months right before Ramadan).
Is it a du'a made by the Prophet () himself of or by any of our Muslim authorities (Sahaba/Shi'a Imams etc.)?

I'd like to know if this du'a is authentic and what sources for that are available?

Comment: Maybe relevant http://www.saaid.net/Doat/Zugail/57.htm ?

Comment: Here is it in the Musnad of Ahmed; http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=121&hid=2257&pid=672345

Comment: Are Shi'a imams considered an authority?

Comment: @QatadaAl-Mubarak if you have a question you should ask it using the ask question link.

Comment: No I was just seeing you. Why did you put "Shia imams" as a "Muslim authority"? Ali Ibn Abi Talib, Hassan and Husayn (may Allah be pleased with them), aren't Shias, they're just Muslims (I don't know about the rest of the imams).

Comment: @QatadaAl-Mubarak from sunni perspective none of these scholars are shi'a what I and almost everybody mean when referring to shi'a imam is those scholars or individuals that shi'a consider imams according the shi'a interpretation of "imam" in this case.

Answer (score 2):

according to [islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/202017)  (A website called "Islam Question and Answer" supervised by Shaykh Muhammad Saalih al-Munajjid) :

> The hadeeth was classed as da‘eef by an-Nawawi in al-Adhkaar and Ibn Rajab in Lataa’if al-Ma‘aarif. It was also classed as da‘eef by al-Albaani in Da‘eef al-Jaami‘